# How to get the count of mails in inbox beside link "inbox" just as we have in GMAIL?

Tags: php, count

I have a document management system, which has similar left panel as we have in our GMAIL now I need to display the counts of items avaialble in different links of left panel till they are seen, as any of them will seen by opening the detail page the count in left panel will decrease.

Comment: Where are the documents stored?

Comment: I store the doc_id in db along with creator id and other level user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to use JavaScript to do this. Here's a quick example I whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/fMyKS/

When any item is opened, it calculates the number of visible items still marked as 'unread'.  You'll need to do more work though, since you'll want to note the item was read in the database.  So instead of counting the number of elements with the class 'unread', send an AJAX request to the server with the id of the current document they are opening.  In your server-side script, mark the item as read in the database and have it reply back with the new number of unread docs.  Take this value and insert it into the HTML. (Note: if you're using AJAX to fetch information about the document when clicked, you can add that logic to the same AJAX request)

Hope that helps!